# How can you reenroll an admin certificate for a Hyperledger Fabric peer if it is already expired

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In the Hyperledger Fabric documentation it states to use the `fabric-ca-client reenroll` if a certificate is about to expire.
Should it work also after a certificate has already expiry?
After doing the `reenroll` request I get the following below:

`reenroll: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid`

Are there any other options to renew already expired certificates?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html#msp-configuration), MSP identities never expire. You should be able to reenroll the admin identity.

However, you can also enroll the admin identity again if you have the enrollment secret.

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

Comment: @antoniovassell What do you get if you add -d to the command like this: `fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054`? It will give you some debug information.

Comment: Error: POST failure of request: POST https://my-ca:7054/enroll
{"hosts":["32942ffab1be"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----CERT-DATA-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"","crl_override":"","label":"","NotBefore":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","NotAfter":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","CAName":""}: Post https://my-ca:7054/enroll: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Comment: above are the details before the failure

Comment: @antoniovassell Are you able to solve it? I am facing the similar issue.

Comment: Hey @HoneyShah, nope. Will update if I do. I think there is something wrong with my ca certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue for the admin user and solved it by running the below command

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=/tmp/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/tmp/crypto-config/hyperledger/tls-ca/admin

fabric-ca-client reenroll -d  -u https://admin:adminpw@ca.org1.example.com:7054 --caname ca-org1
```

You will get two .pem files

```
Stored client certificate at /tmp/crypto-config/hyperledger/tls-ca/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
Stored root CA certificate at /tmp/crypto-config/hyperledger/tls-ca/admin/msp/cacerts/ca-org1-example.com-com-7054-ca-org1.pem
```

But I didn't find any documentation for javascript libraries to use reenroll function.  if anyone has please post links